# React+Next.js+Firebase:Auth URL changes to username and password after signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, url, next.js

I am using React + Next.js + Firebase.Auth. I have a form for email and password. And on submit, it calls onSubmit method and successfully displays `"onSubmit",user` in the console. But the `"After"` is not being shown in the console. Also, the url changes to the email and password that should be used for the auth.

ex)`http://localhost:3000/signin?email=aaa@gmail.com&password=abc123`

Also it throws `(TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` inside`onAuthStateChanged`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { SignUpLink } from '../SignUp';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firebase } from '../../Firebase'

const SignInPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>SignIn</h1>
    <SignInForm />
    <SignUpLink />
  </div>
);

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  error: null,
  user: null
};

async function onSignInButton () {
  console.log("Sign In Butrton")
  console.log("Sign In Done")
}

const SignInButton = () => (
  <Button type="primary" onClick={onSignInButton}>
    Sign In
  </Button>
);


class SignInFormBase extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps ({ Component, ctx }) {

    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};

    return { pageProps };
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { ...INITIAL_STATE }
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log("onSubmit", this.state)
    firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code
        var errorMessage = error.message
        console.log(errorMessage)
        // ...
      });
    firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        //
        this.setState({ user: user })
        console.log("User", this.state.user)
      } else {
        // Handle error
      }
    })
    console.log("After")
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  };

  render () {
    const { email, password, error } = this.state;

    const isInvalid = password === '' || email === ''

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email Address"
        />
        <input
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit">
          Sign In
        </button>
        {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Scope

`this` is not at the right context because you declare an anon function with the keyword function. When you do this you create a new scope. That means that the `this` keyword means "this function" not "this react class".

To avoid this use the arrow function `() => {}`

These functions pass the `this` along.

#### change this

```
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        //
        this.setState({ user: user })
        console.log("User", this.state.user)
      } else {
        // Handle error
      }
    })
```

#### to this

```
firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        //
        this.setState({ user: user })
        console.log("User", this.state.user)
      } else {
        // Handle error
      }
    })
```

Comment: no problem, just make sure you understand context and this.